# verilog compiler error: near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write traffic light FSM code for green, yellow, red which has a delay of 20 time units. It goes from Green-yellow-red-yellow- green. This is my code and I'm getting error while using 'repeat' for delay.

Errors:

> Error: C:/Users/Desktop/Design/tlights.v(33): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'
>   Error: C:/Users/Desktop/Design/tlights.v(37): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'
>   Error: C:/Users/Desktop/Design/tlights.v(44): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';'

```
`define delay 20;
 module tlights(clk, rst, y);

 input clk, rst;
 output [1:0]y;
 reg [1:0]y;
 reg [1:0] cs,ns;
 integer p;

 parameter red = 2'd2;
 parameter orange = 2'd1;
 parameter green = 2'd0;

 parameter s0 = 2'd0;
 parameter s1 = 2'd1;
 parameter s2 = 2'd2;


 always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
 begin
 if(!rst)
 begin
  cs<=s0;
 end
 else
  cs<=ns;
 end

 always@(cs)
 begin
 case(cs)
        s0: begin 
             repeat (`delay) @(posedge clk); // <-- Error here
                ns=s1;
             end
        s1: begin
             repeat (`delay) @(posedge clk); // <-- Error here
             if (p==0)
                  ns =s2;
                else 
                 ns=s0;
            end
        s2:    begin 
              repeat (`delay) @(posedge clk); // <-- Error here
                 ns<=s1;
               end
        default: ns<=s0;
      endcase
   end 

  always@ (cs)
  begin
    case(cs)
      s0:begin 
          y<=2'b00; 
          p<=0;
         end
      s1:y<=2'b01; 
      s2:begin 
         y<=2'b10; 
         p<=1;
         end         
  endcase
 end
 endmodule
```

Comment: For those reviewing for close votes. The bug is "simple typographical", _however_ `define`s are inherently challenging to debug. Compilers only state errors on the line the macro is used and rarely give hits to the error inside the macro itself. I suggest this question to remain open unless a duplicate question can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `` `define `` statement. `` `define `` is similar to `#define` in C/C++. The statements do literal substitution and the terminator is end of line, not a semi-colon. `` repeat (`delay) `` means `repeat ( 20; )`. Remove the `;` and it will simulate.

Even with with the correction it will not synthesize. Blocking statements (i.e. `@`,`#`, and `wait`) are not allowed inside combinational logic. To be synthesizable, you'll need to add some flip-flops for a counter. Your next state and next counter combinational logic should look something like the following:

```
always @* begin
  // default value
  ns = cs;
  next_counter  = counter + 1;
  // update value
  case(cs)
    s0: begin
      if (counter >= `delay) begin
        ns = s1;
        next_counter = 0;
      end
    end
   /* ... */
  endcase
end
```

Also, remember to assign flops with non-blocking (`<=`). Blocking (`=`) for assigning combinational logic.

Comment: I did try without semicolon. It didn't work. It is throwing the same error.

Comment: ***@Greg***, : I was able to compile it with semi-colon also, provide if i change the ___`define delay 20___. to ___parameter delay = 20___. So, I'm not sure if the error is related to the semi-colon.

Comment: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Nr , all I did was comment you your semicolon and it simulated. `parameter` is better though, define is global space which should have minimum cluttered.

Comment: ___Greg___:Actually, i was able to compile it both with and without semi-colon, if i change the ___`define delay 20___ to ___parameter delay = 20___. I'm confused now.

Comment: Its "*`define delay 20*" or "*parameter delay = 20;*" I recommend sticking with parameter, declared inside the module.